# GNU Parallel output to stdout using --round-robin

Tags: gnu-parallel

I'm trying to use GNU Parallel to help me process some remote files that I don't want to save locally.

My command looks somewhat like that:

```
python list_files.py | \
  parallel -j5 'aws s3 cp s3://s3-bucket/{} -' | \
    parallel -j5 --round --pipe -l 5000 "python process_and_print.py"
```

`process_and_print.py` prints output for some input lines, but that output doesn't get to stdout immediately like I expected, instead I only see the output after the process is finished. If I remove the `--round` parameter is all works as expected.

Where does all that data get saved? Do I have a way to print it to stdout, line by line, without buffering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where does all that data get saved?

All buffered output from GNU Parallel is buffered in temporary files in $TMPDIR / `--tmpdir` which defaults to `/tmp`. You cannot see the files, as they are immediately removed (but kept open) to avoid you having to clean up, if GNU Parallel is killed.

> Do I have a way to print it to stdout, line by line,

`--line-buffer`

> without buffering?

`-u` disables buffering all together, but then you cannot guarantee line-by-line.

`--line-buffer` buffers a full line in memory from version 20170822 and thus does not buffer in `/tmp`.